# Difference between $this->getData() or $this->getResource()

Tags: collection, products, getresource

In my `Collection.php` when i get the collection by `$this->getData()` is give me collection.

But it create some other problem for me .

Now i use `$this->getResource()` then problem solved But it not return `data` .

Can any one here, Please tell me why collection is empty when i use `$this->getResource()` ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it resolved

i just clone my $collection .

```
$collection= clone $this;
```

it work now.